# Delete operation works only on first page

Tags: jquery, spring, datatables

Delete operation is not working when using jQuery DataTables plugin in second page onwards. Delete operation works on first page and sorting/pagination also work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to use delegated event handlers because only first page elements exist in DOM.

For example:

```
$('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-delete', function(e){
   // your code
});
```

See [jQuery DataTables – Why click event handler does not work](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-why-click-event-handler-does-not-work/) for more information.